# What influenced the novel 'Definitely Maybe' by the Strugatsky's?

Tags: inspiration, strugatsky-brothers

For those who have read [Definitely Maybe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/650777.Definitely_Maybe) by the Strugatsky brothers or know a bit about 1970's Russia, the Brezhnev Era or how the Mikhail Kheifets case with Boris Strugatsky testifying as a witness:

**What served as an influence or inspiration for the themes and characters of this novel?**

Comment: What is it exactly you want?

Comment: A bit of [context here](https://www.theparisreview.org/blog/2015/05/11/give-me-that-old-time-socialist-utopia/) but i think you'll have more luck on other sci-fi forums, or perhaps on   [literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Where the heck did the "definitely maybe" come from in English Wikipedia??? The official name of the book is "За миллиард лет до конца света" (A billion years before the end of the world") and a subtitle is "Рукопись, обнаруженная при странных обстоятельствах" ("A manuscript discovered in strange circumstances").

Comment: And the Kheifets case definitely had an impact; from BNS interview: https://web.archive.org/web/20140219172940/http://www.rusf.ru/abs/books/publ34.htm

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Haha, yes. When i saw the question with the unfamiliar title i hoped it was a book of the brothers i missed and now i get to read it. But at least to hungarian it was translated correctly. My dad had a copy. About the interview - it does answer the question,  but i am not sure OP knows Russian. ..

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Perhaps in the case of Kheifets, if the answer is in the interview, you provide an answer explaining what it said. I also cannot read or speak Russian. *A Billion Years Before the End of the World* is my favourite Strugatsky Brothers novel. The original title is much, much better than the anondyne English language edition title. Many books are published under different titles; some better than others.

Comment: @a4android - sorry, i'm mostly retired from SFF site and SE in general.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Thank you for the courtesy of letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

Malyanov (with his living apartment) was inspired by Boris Strugatsky himself.
Vecherovsky was inspired partly by Yuri Manin and partly by certain (unknown to me) physicist.
Snegovoy was inspired by the rocket engineer (and writer) Alexander Meyerov.
The case of Kheifets, of course, served as the inspiration for all the “characters under pressure” stuff.